# Result in the array fetched from a regular expression using php

Tags: php, regex

I had fetched some result from a regular expression using.

```
$res = "there are many restaurants in the city. Restaurants like xyz,abc. one restaurant like.....";

$pattern = '/restaurants?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, substr($res,10), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

For this regular expression, my output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => restaurants
            [1] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Restaurants
            [1] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => restaurant
            [1] => 60
        )

)
```

in the [0] index, i find the matched strings. But, I dont know the values came in the [1] index like `5` , `30` , `60`. Please help me in finding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
```

This captures the offset. These numbers tell you where the string was found.

Please read the manual first. 
http://php.net/preg_match_all